# Last entry in the table oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to create a query in an oracle that will show the last entry in the table that I made, I tried through max and through date, but after max, query is not accurate, and due date shows all dates, I will be grateful for your help)

after the date

```
select seal_number 
  from SEC_OBJECT_SEALING 
 where SEALING_OBJECT = :P26_OBJECT_UNPLUG 
   and (to_date(data ,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') = 
       (select max(to_date(data ,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) from SEC_OBJECT_SEALING)
```

through max

```
select seal_number 
  from SEC_OBJECT_SEALING 
 where SEALING_OBJECT = :P26_OBJECT_UNPLUG 
   and id = (select max(id) from SEC_OBJECT_SEALING)
```

Comment: Please **edit your question** and provide sample data and expected results. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle 12+, use `fetch`:

```
select seal_number
from SEC_OBJECT_SEALING
where SEALING_OBJECT = :P26_OBJECT_UNPLUG 
order by data desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In earlier versions, use a subquery:

```
select sos.*
from (select seal_number
      from SEC_OBJECT_SEALING
      where SEALING_OBJECT = :P26_OBJECT_UNPLUG 
      order by data desc
     ) sos
where rownum = 1;
```